# How can I define SoundManager2 as a Media Element Source in Web Audio API

Tags: html, audio, html5-audio, web-audio-api, soundmanager2

I know that web audio api can take an `<audio>` element as it's media source, (for frequency data, etc), however SoundManager2 does not seem to create an `<audio>` tag, and as such I'm not sure what I would provide as the source, in order to play sounds using SoundManager2, and use that as a source to provide visualizations using web audio.

The reason for the split is because SoundManager2 is well documented and can relay information such as bytes loaded, schedule events at certain times in audio, and other such things that either don't yet exist or are simply hard to find out about in the web audio api. However I would like to avoid the requirement of flash for visualizations in SoundManager and use Web Audop API for that side of things.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The `<audio>` element is really buried in SoundManager2, but you can find it like this:

```
soundManager.onready = function() {
    audioElement = soundManager.sounds[soundManager.soundIDs[0]]._a;
    webAudioSource = audioContext.createMediaElementSource(audioElement);
}
```

Like in @MarijnS95's example, you'll need to connect the Media Element Source Node to the Audio Context Destination Node in order to hear it. This is because Web Audio hijacks the element's audio output. But SoundManager will still be able to control the play/pause/timing functionality and now you can make visualizations / process the sound with web audio.

Comment: Wow thanks for the belated answer. Not working with this library any more for now but when I do next this will likely come in handy. Thanks!

Comment: @talkscheap I am trying to set this up as you sugjested any idea why the song would stop playing and when i force it to play it plays with no volume or seemingly doesnt play... :(

Comment: to get _a property, it is cleaner to do : audioElement = soundManager.getSoundById("YourSoundId")._a

Answer (score 1):

I do not know how this would works in soundmanager2, but in plain javascript it is pretty simple. You just create a `MediaElementNode` and assing an `audio` or `video` tag to it. So my guess is that you must specify the html object to soundmanager2. (you can either do this by creating an audio element in javascript: `player = new Audio();` or by adding the `<audio id="player"></audio>` tags to your html and get them with `document.getElementById('player');`

Basic example:

```
function init() {
    player = new Audio();
    window.context = new webkitAudioContext()||AudioContext();
    audioSource = context.createMediaElementSource(player);
    audioSource.connect(context.destination);
}
```

[Source](http://www.w3.org/TR/webaudio/#MediaElementAudioSourceNode)
[jsfiddle with example](http://jsfiddle.net/MarijnS95/DuPE6/)

I hope this will give you a step in the right direction, to find how to do this in soundmanager2.

Comment: Sadly upon inspection, things being abstracted in soundmanager2 makes this not possible until the api is implemented there. Waiting game for now.

Comment: After checking the soundmanager2 js file I noticed that it works through a flash object. So you can't not work with flash with soundmanger2. The only media elements you can connect with the audio api are the `<audio>` and `<video>` tag. My question to you is, what are you exacly trying to do with soundmanager2? If you only want to play music with it and have a slider bar for the time like this exmple](http://imgur.com/1LFJULt), you'd better go with the web audio api for everything. Do you already have something working for the visualiser?

Comment: You can not work with flash, and force it into html5 only mode. Eg at the moment I simply don't give it any urls to swf files, they don't even exist on my server, still works though. And Web audio Api sadly lacks things like events at the moment, plus I have a whole thing built around sm2

Comment: You are right! After some searching I found some of the audio elements: `audioClone = new Audio(s._iO.url);`, `s._a = new Audio(instanceOptions.url);` and this one: `var a = (Audio !== _undefined ? (isOpera && opera.version() < 10 ? new Audio(null) : new Audio()) : null),`, so you either need to spaudioObject)`.

Comment: I have found out that the creator of SoundManager2 has this in an experimental branch and as such I shall wait for stability and go that route, as I can live without this data. Thank you for the help, however.